# Converting Python Function to Hive UDAF

Tags: java, python, hive

How do I convert the following Python function, `longToDigitArray` to a HiveQL UDAF? I am not familiar with Java.

```
# convert source (e.g. 2305843012434919424, into a list of source flags)
# Desired behavior:
# Input: longToDigitArray(2305843012434919424)
# Output: [31, 32, 62]

def longToDigitArray(x):
    a=[]
    i=1 
    try:
        x=long(x)
    except:
        return(a)
    while (x!=0):
        if (x & 1): # "Bitwise AND" &: Returns a 1 in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of both operands are 1's.
            a.append(i)
        x = (x >> 1) # bitwise right-shift 1
        i = i+1
    return(a)
```

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: You can register Python functions as Hive UDF's

Comment: @cricket_007 - I wish, but I assume you are talking about scripts used in a TRANSFORM clause, not UDF.

Comment: @Dudu Is that not the same thing? Anyways, Pig definitely allows Python UDF, though PySpark would be more SQL friendly.

Comment: may be a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27391006/how-to-write-a-python-udf-for-user-defined-aggregate-function-in-hive#27494176

Comment: @cricket_007 - No, not the same thing. STREAM returns a row set and this is what you have - you can't select any other column. Think on a reasonable scenario where I want to use 3 scalar UDF on the same record.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Alright fine. Anyway, this question is asking for us to translate code. Java has ArrayLists, casting and bit shifting, so I suggest OP do a little research.